# Is it possible to "fake" the src attribute of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I try to add dynamically an iframe to a web page using JavaScript. I would like to know if that's possible to set the src attribute of my iframe without using another html file via an URL.
I mean is there a way to "fake" the html for the src attribute file with a JS variable where we I can set my code (which is JS itself) ?
I would use the DOM createElement to create the iframe in jQuery.

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you want a frame? What's wrong with just using a div and `overflow: scroll`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could look into [`data:`URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI).

```
<iframe src="data:text/html, .... URLencoded HTML data ....">
```

alternatively

```
<iframe src="data:text/html;base64, .... base64 encoded HTML data ....">
```

The scheme is supported by IE >= 8 [(MSDN source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(VS.85).aspx), Firefox, Safari 3+ and Opera.

It has differing length limits. Opera is said to cut off at about 4 kilobytes; Internet Explorer at 32 kilobytes. Firefox has no explicit length limit.

More on data URIs and tools for converting at [Mozilla Developer Central](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs)

Comment: It seems to be what I need. Do you know if there is a way to create the code that goes into the HTML data using an Element or I don't know how, and then use it the the src ? Because my code is JavaScript and for the moment I can not do it directly. But it will try again.

Comment: @Lucas jQuery's `.html()` should give you the HTML contents of any element. `encodeURIComponent()` should encode it properly for use in the first example. There is no native `base64()` implementation in JS but better go with the URIencoded way, as base64 bloats the code by 33%.

Comment: In fact that is still not working but my current error is an "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL, Domains, protocols and ports must match" error. I will do other searches for that. But thanks =)

Comment: @Lucas awww, that's not nice. Maybe worth another question, there should be a way around that if you create the element yourself.

Comment: @Pekka the code I want to add into the iframe is a google ad, that call for a JS google code, which it itself using an iframe. That's why it doesn't like it I think. I think I saw somewhere that I could be able to fix this by setting the domain etc.
I will try it by my own a bit then ask a question if I can't do it alone!

Comment: Just in case, The full error is:
"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///home/lucas/Bureau/google_ad.html from frame with URL data:text/html, <script>google_comments</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="google_path.js"></script>. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

"file:///home/lucas/Bureau/google_ad.html" is my experimental file to try things.
"<script>google_comments</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="google_path.js"></script>" is my (simplified) ad code.

Comment: @Lucas first step, move away from `file://` urls to a local or remote web server. Browsers are awfully strict with those.

Comment: @Lucas I'd say that calls for a question of its own, with code and everything.

Comment: @Pekka yes I have already done that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473416/problem-to-display-dynamically-a-javascript-google-ad-in-an-iframe-using-jquery/3474598#3474598 (=

Comment: I'm looking to populate an iframe with pdf files around 200Kb from a Java applet using javascript... do you think this would be possible with this solution?

Comment: @jaime I'm not sure whether and how data URIs work with the PDF viewer plugin. Might be worth a try though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're controlling the iframe entirely client-side, and never need to make server-side requests with that iframe, it's proably easier to style a div to appear like an iframe (look into the `overflow` property), where you'll have far simpler and more direct control to the DOM contents of that div.

Comment: I do server-side requests, that's why I use DOM

Answer (score -1):

following code should do what you want.

you can leave the src attribute empty.

```
var yourcontent="<div>your stuff</div>";
window.frames['frame_name'].document.write=yourcontent;
```

Comment: I cannot do that after the page is loaded.