# How to echo iframe with variable

Tags: php, variables, iframe

Im scraping some websites and saving the data and then echo the data like this:

```
echo $html->save();
```

The `$html` part is a variable which holds the complete website. I would like to echo the complete page in iframe, usually I would put a source `src="file.php?url=http://somewebsite.com"` How do I echo the variable instead including the Iframe:

```
echo '<iframe src="$html->save()"></iframe>';
```

Is this somewhat how its done, or am I completely of?

Im using simple-html-dom and CURL like this:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
require_once('url_to_absolute.php');



$url = $_GET['url'];

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($curl_scraped_page, true, false);
    


foreach($html->find('a') as $a) {
    $a->href = url_to_absolute($url, $a->href);
}






echo $html->save();

$html->clear();
```

Comment: Would you be willing to explain the context? I'd be sad if I assisted you in doing something naughty.

Comment: @George Cummins There is nothing naughty about scraping. Im scraping a news website (legal) and would like to show the content in iframe. However instead of having a regular iframe inside a HTML page I would rather echo the iframe (with its content).

Comment: Does `$html->save()` return HTML data?  If so, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6102636

Comment: Why are people downvoting..?? Very useful question..nothing on Google..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called **`magicalbuffer.php`**. Make all your saves and craws on it, and on iframe:

```
<iframe src="magicalbuffer.php?parameterToPassToScrapper=valueToPassToScrapper"></iframe>
```

**OR**

According with that **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462800/1146264)**

```
printf('<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,%s"></iframe>', base64_encode($html->save()));
```

Comment: I would like to echo the iframe (not a php file with parameter inside Iframe)

Comment: Inside that file you should echo your HTML.

Comment: Thank you but Im getting 'some weird plain text' like this `++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++var+context++=+{ ++++'dc_params'+:+'', ++++'category'+:+'home', ++++'stir_webdir'+:+'voorpagina', ++++'article_id'+:+'', ++++'article_name'+:+'', ++++'article_author'+:+'' ++};` Definitely not the html page Im scraping:)

Comment: I did a mistake within data type, so i've updated with base64 :P

Answer (score 1):

To echo scraped data, don't use an iframe. Instead, echo the data into an appropriate container such as a div:

```
echo '<div>' . $html->save() . '</div>';
```

If you wish to avoid encapsulating your HTML in PHP, do:

```
?>
<div><?php echo $html-save(); ?>"></div>
<?php
```

This is often cleaner and easier to troubleshoot, especially if you are producing a lot of HTML in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the input but the first and second code don't work. I can't use the last code in my project. I have updated my question.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work." Do you get an error? Wrong output? What does `$html` contain?

Comment: Im getting a 'blank' iframe with nothing in it

Comment: Are you aware that the `src` attribute should have only a URL, not HTML? Your question is unclear about whether `$html` contains scraped data or a URL.

Comment: $html contains scraped data, I already mentioned this in my question:)

Comment: Then you don't need an iframe. You need some other container to display your data. I'll update my question with details.

Comment: I would really like (just) the Iframe if its possible..It has to do with my project..

Comment: Iframes are not suitable for echoing scraped content. They can only take a URL parameter. The URL is then loaded by the browser at render time.

Comment: I would like to keep the "content" clean and intact with head/body and everything. If I use a div the whole markup gets destroyed, you would get something like this <div><html><body>content and so on...not good for my project..If its not possible, to bad:( I will accept your answer if nothing else comes along because I would assume it is not possible like you mentioned

Comment: A browser cannot properly render multiple `<html>` or `<body>` elements. If you want to display the HTML as-is, you can dump the contents in a `<textarea>`. If you want to render the page, you can use an iframe but need to specify the URL as the `src` attribute rather than scraping the data. This prompts the browser to begin rendering the content of the iframe as a separate document.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time:) And thanks for `<textarea>` did not know about that, will experiment with it